# Is JavaScript object injection exploitable?

Tags: javascript, json, object-injection

I'm testing a site that behaves like this:

1. When I change my username, I submit a POST request with JSON data like this `{"username":"John"}`.
2. If I change that to for example `{"username":{"test":"test"}}`, my username is printed like this: `[object Object]`
3. Therefore I concluded that I can inject objects and have tried to override the toString method of my object doing this: `{"username":{"test":"test","toString":"function() {return 1;}"}}`, but when I load a page where the username should be printed, I just get a runtime error in the console saying that toString is not a function.

I assume that I have successfully managed to overwrite the toString method, but it seems that I have just replaced it with a string, and therefore it is not a method anymore and cannot be executed.

Any ideas if this could be exploitable?

Comment: I don't want to make this an answer since it's so simple, but the reason toString() isn't a function is because you overrode it as a string. Simply remove quotes around your function definition and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am actually only in the control of the input JSON data, and the problem is if I remove the quotes, than it is not a valid JSON anymore and does not get parsed by the server :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON can not be used for object injection in JavaScript the way your question suggests.

[JSON only allows](https://www.json.org/) strings, numbers, objects, arrays, booleans and null. It does not allow functions. So what you are passing there might look like a function, but it is not one. It is just a string that happends to contain some code for a function. Unless there is something on the server explicitly taking strings and executing them as code (e.g. `eval`), the code will not be executed. JSON deserialization does not execute code in strings.

So why the error message? When you ask JavaScript to treat a variable as a string (e.g. print it), it tries to convert it to a string if it is not already one. This is done by trying to call the member `toString`. But you have set it to be a string, not a function, so it can not be called. Hence the error.